# proving identity for the sums of two series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that for $a\ne0, -2, -4, \dots$
$$\frac1{\sqrt{1-x}}\left[\frac1a+\frac12\frac{x}{a+2}+\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot4}\frac{x^2}{a+4}+\cdots\right]=\frac1a\left[1+\frac{a+1}{a+2}x+\frac{(a+1)(a+3)}{(a+2)(a+4)}x^2+\cdots\right]$$
So I tried to make the product by expanding the first term into power series and, assuming I didn't make any mistake, this identity boils down to: $$(-1)^n\sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom{-\frac12}{m}\binom{-\frac12}{n-m}\frac1{a+2m}=\frac{(a+1)(a+3)\cdots(a+2n-1)}{a(a+2)(a+4)\cdots(a+2n)}$$for $n\ge1$ (I'm just equating the corresponding coefficients for the $n$-th powers).
I thought that I could evaluate that sum by considering $\sum\binom{-\frac12}{m}\binom{-\frac12}{n-m}x^{a+2m-1}$ and then integrating from $0$ to $1$. Still this sum is troublesome (one can factor out $x^{a-1}$ and put $x^2 = y$ for simplicity but again it doesn't really ring any bell to me).
I also tried to differentiate both sides using the rule for the $n$-th derivative of a product, but a similar sum arises, so that way also is pointless.
What's the best way to solve this? I can accept hints too :)